# Is Soaking and Sprouting Lentils Unsanitary?

Tags: food-safety, lentils, sprouting

I got into sprouting lentils for salads and soups, then I read that it's a breeding ground for bacteria. 
Is it true that sprouting lentils is dangerous and unsanitary? 
Is soaking also dangerous?

Do you still sprout lentils or is the risk too great?

Comment: There are many questions here, can you [edit] to focus on one aspect you want to know? For what is worth, I sprouted and ate lentils many times as well as other beans. Anything can be unsanitary if you don't keep proper hygiene.

Comment: @Luciano edited for clarity